# Data Not Available You do not have Edit access to one of the two records you are trying to merge

Tags: apex, sharing, sharing-rule

I am getting following error while viewing record in salesforce. But same record is visible in related list of parent opportunity record and also I can even query this record with SOQL query using workbench.

**Opportunity related list - record is visible (1st record)**
[image]

**Error after navigating to record:**

[image]

**Record available via SOQL**
[image]

As this is bad data, when I try to delete with user having modify all data permission or user with system administrator profile, getting following error

> Delete failed. First exception on row 1 with id abc5Y000000NPtiUAG;
> first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id:
> []

I have modify all and delete object level permission for the custom object of the record I am trying to delete. The deletion is also failing with the same error via the apex code which executed in system mode context.

Any help is much appreciated!